# Filter Left Join Unique Value

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables and need to choose only the unique value from the left join.
This is the code I tested with.

First table - answered  (Field Name - src)

Second Table - noanswered (Field Name - src2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT src2 
FROM answerd 
RIGHT noanswered ON answerd.src = noanswered.src2 
WHERE answerd.src IS Not NULL;
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You have a table of answered and unanswered questions. How can such tables even have an intersection? What's wrong with simply selecting unique rows from the `answered` table?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM answered
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM noanswered 
                   WHERE answered.src = noanswered.src2 );
```